# msvcrt9 runtime

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, msvcr90.dll

Sounds ridiculous, but I need to install the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161" on win2008-R2 64bit

[I go here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582&WT.mc_id=MSCOM_EN_US_DLC_DETAILS_121LSUS007998)

Run the installer, everything's fine.
But after the reboot, I don't see the entry in the "Program and features" ?
And, of course, my dll -which is linked against vc9- cannot find the crt.

Where's my mistake ?

Comment: You installed the x86 version of the CRT. If you're trying to run an x64 application, this isn't the one you want.

Comment: No, In fact I'm running an x86 app. In fact I just think the link isn't good :) By the way all these manifest are exhausting. Do you think if a rollup is existing ?

Comment: The Windows-on-Windows 64-bit (WoW64) subsystem which allows execution of 32-bit applications is an optional component in Windows Server 2008 r2. Do you have that component installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is for the SP 1 version of the runtime. Googling the version number you mention suggests you need the original release, not sp1. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29).